# Django models with self create properties

Tags: django, model

Let's pretend that you're creating web application.
You have users in your app and these users have collections of pictures, books and other.
They can add to their collections items (accordingly books, pictures e.g.).
Example of book fields:
_author
_title
_desription

But what if they want add another information about this book like preview picture, pages quantity and other(SOMETHING I DON'T KNOW, his own field in runtime)  link and other information. How can i implement it with django models??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you can create another model with ForeignKey for other informations.

First create a model for standart information. After create a second model with ForeignKey for create a connection to first model information.

You can check ForeignKey information page for how to use it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: no i mean he can define field name and also define field type by himself( in runtime)